# why does an n x n invertible matrix has n eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm confused about the number of eigenvalues a matrix as given that it is invertible. Say I have invertible matrix $A$ which is $n$ x $n$. My understanding is that it will have $n$ eigenvalues. Can someone explain why? I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Invertibility doesn't matter. The matrix has $n$ eigenvalues counted "with multiplicity," which is a little subtle in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the characteristic polynomial of your matrix, you will find a polynomial of degree $n$, which has $n$ roots over $\mathbb{C}$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Those roots are your eigenvalues. If your matrix is invertible, you can prove that $0$ is not a root of your characteristic polynomial, so perhaps you mean`t  that an invertible matrix has $n$ non-zero eigenvalues?